# Factories in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

It appear you can write Factories in Laravel.

According to doumentation: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#writing-factories

It appear Factories for the model/database related.

Is it possible to write Factories for non model related?

For example of two classes:

```
class Car {
  public function drive() { }
} 

Class Bike {
 public function ride() { }
}
```

Rather than using `(new Car)->drive()` I would like to use `Transport` Factory to class the class.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking for [Mockeries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mocking)

Comment: @apokryfos No I do not want to mock. I want to use factory pattern something like `Transport::build('car')->drive();` I wonder if Laravel support such thing.

Comment: Does car have dependencies or would it literally evaluate to `(new Car)->drive()`?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back if you mean the factory pattern then no, you'll have to implement this on your own. Laravel uses the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container) which works differently but provides a similar (if not better) result. However note that the Factory you're linking to is not what you think it is. That is for database testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this

```
class Transport
{
    public static function build($vehicle)
    {
        return new $vehicle;
    }
}

interface Vehicle
{
    public function drive();
}

class Car implements Vehicle
{
    public function drive()
    {
        // the way a car drives
    }
}

class Bike implements Vehicle
{
    public function drive()
    {
        // the way a bike drives
    }
}

class Something
{
    public function someFunc()
    {
        Transport::build('Car')->drive();
    }
}
```

Here without having separate methods like `drive()` and `ride()` for `Car` and `Bike` classes, I just added `drive()` method. Then `Bike` and `Car` bind to the `Vehicle` contract.

So then we just need to pass either a `Car` or a `Bike` to `Transport::build('Car')->drive();`

Answer (score 0):

We can create Factory pattern like `Transport::build('car')->drive();` as per following.

```
//Create a class for the dynamic object
class Transport{
    public static function build($vehicle)
    {
        return new $vehicle;
    }
}

//Normal class
class Car {
  public function drive() {

  }
}

//call factory class for dynamic object
Transport::build('Car')->drive();
```